# Лабораторная по выводу в файл (С++)

Tags: c++

Добрый вечер. Помогите, пожалуйста, с заданием по чтению и записи в файл. Само задание на картинке.
[image]

Вот моя структура **ScanInfo.h**

```
#include "stdafx.h"

struct ScanInfo {
    std::string model;
    int price;
    double x_size;
    double y_size;
    int optr;
    int grey;
};
```

вот код программы

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ScanInfo.h"

ScanInfo CreateScan ();
std::string SetModelName();
int SetOpticalResolution();

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    using namespace std;
    setlocale (LC_ALL, "Russian");

    int n;
    cout << "Введите n = ";
    cin >> n;

    ScanInfo *scanList = new ScanInfo[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        scanList[i] = CreateScan(); 
    }

    FILE *file;
    if ((file = fopen("d:\\C++\\Training\\Files\\output.out", "w+b")) == 0)
    {
        cout << "Ошибка cоздания файла"; return 1;
    }


    fclose(file);
    delete [] scanList;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}


ScanInfo CreateScan () {
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    ScanInfo scanInfo;
    scanInfo.model = SetModelName();
    scanInfo.price = rand()%3000 + 1000;
    scanInfo.x_size = rand()%50 + 200;
    scanInfo.y_size = rand()%50 + 200;
    scanInfo.optr = SetOpticalResolution();
    scanInfo.grey = rand()%50 + 200;

    return scanInfo;
}

std::string SetModelName() {
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    int n = rand()%5 + 1;
    std::string modelName;
    switch(n)
    {
    case 1:
        modelName = "Canon"; break; 
    case 2: 
        modelName = "Epson"; break;
    case 3: 
        modelName = "Nikon"; break;
    case 4: 
        modelName = "Panasonic"; break;
    case 5: 
        modelName = "Xerox"; break;
    default:
        modelName = "Untitled"; break;
    }
    return modelName;
}

int SetOpticalResolution() {
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    int n = rand()%5 + 1;
    int opticalResolution;
    switch(n)
    {
    case 1:
        opticalResolution = 1200; break; 
    case 2: 
        opticalResolution = 1800; break;
    case 3: 
        opticalResolution = 2400; break;
    case 4: 
        opticalResolution = 3600; break;
    case 5: 
        opticalResolution = 4800; break;
    default:
        opticalResolution = 0; break;
    }
    return opticalResolution;
}
```

Не могу разобраться, как мне записать в первые два байта int и увеличивать его на +1 при каждой записи в файл и как записать в файл записи о сканерах, чтобы они шли друг за другом без пропусков и как потом считывать из файла запись по её номеру?

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так:

```
short buffer = (short)n;
fwrite(buffer, 1, 2, file);   // Не надо это значение увеличивать, мы и так его знаем, когда надо
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
  fwrite(scanList[i].model.c_str(), 1, scanList[i].model.length() + 1, file);
  fwrite(scanList[i].price, 1, sizeof(scanList[i].price), file);
  ...
}
```

При чтении распознать конец строки в каждой записи можно будет по 0-му байту. А доступ к произвольной записи одной операцией сделать не получится. Если бы у Вас остались char model[25], можно было бы одним одним оператором fwrite записать всю структуру. И записи были бы одного размера. А с std::string получается посложнее. Хотя можно и из std::string cкопировать в char buffer[25] и записать его - тогда всё будет просто.